# How can I return an AngularJS promise from a function return?

Tags: angularjs

I have this Typescript / Javascript function:

```
wordFormRowClicked = (wf): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    if (this.wordFormIdentity != wf.wordFormIdentity) {
        angular.forEach(self.word.wordForms, function (wf, key) {
            var wordFormNgForm = 'wordFormNgForm_' + wf.wordFormIdentity;
            if (self[wordFormNgForm].$pristine) {
                ;
            } else {
                self.wordFormUpdate(wf).then((): any => {
                    self[wordFormNgForm].$setPristine();
                });
            }
        });
        this.wordFormIdentity = wf.wordFormIdentity;
    }
}
```

self.wordFormUpdate(wf) returns a promise and so gives the correct return types but if wordFormUpdate is not called then it does not return a promise and also there is a possibility that multiple wordFormUpdates will be called and I have to ensure they have all finished before returning.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `wordFormRowClicked` function must return a promise:

```
var _this = this;
wordFormRowClicked = function (wf) {
    var self = _this;
    var promises = [];
    if (_this.wordFormIdentity != wf.wordFormIdentity) {
        angular.forEach(self.word.wordForms, function (wf, key) {
            var wordFormNgForm = 'wordFormNgForm_' + wf.wordFormIdentity;
            if (self[wordFormNgForm].$pristine) {
                ;
            }
            else {
                var updatePromise = self.wordFormUpdate(wf).then(function () {
                    return self[wordFormNgForm].$setPristine();
                });
                promises.push(updatePromise);
            }
        });

    }
    return $q.all(promises);
};
wordFormRowClicked.then(function () {
    //at this point all promises are resolved
    this.wordFormIdentity = wf.wordFormIdentity;
});
```